# quicklook html files as text, not rendered html?

Tags: html, macos, quicklook

OSX's Quicklook renders HTML (with the plugin /System/Library/Quicklook/Web.qlgenerator). I'd like to see plain text, as if I'd renamed the .html as .txt (that's not a solution and not only because it's awkward: I'm hoping that if the HTML rendering is turned off the code-coloring Quicklook plugin I use will kick in, and Quicklook will show me pretty HTML code).

I haven't been able to turn off HTML without killing Quicklook html support, which is what happens when I remove the plugin. I don't really know what I'm looking at in info.plist, but removing the public.html line is just as bad.

Tips?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is related to: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51816/quicklook-html-plugin.

Here is a solution that works (tested on Mac OS X 10.7.5):

1. /install [qlcolorcode](https://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/downloads/detail?name=QLColorCode-2.0.2.tgz&can=2&q=) (or [qlstephen](https://github.com/downloads/whomwah/qlstephen/QLStephen.qlgenerator.zip))
2. Edit `/System/Library/Quicklook/Web.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist` and comment the two lines as below:

   ```
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
   <array>
     <string>com.apple.webarchive</string>
     <!-- <string>public.html</string> -->
     <!-- <string>public.xhtml</string> -->
     <string>public.svg-image</string>
   </array>
   ```
3. Add the two lines removed above under the same `<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>` into `~/Library/QuickLook/QLColorCode.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist` (or `~/Library/QuickLook/QLStephen.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist`)
4. Press Command+Option+Esc and restart Finder.

Now QuickLook should display the source code of HTML files (with syntax highlighting if you use qlcolorcode) instead of rendering them.

Comment: I didn't have to comment out the lines from `/System/Library/Quicklook/Web.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist`. Just adding them to `~/Library/QuickLook/QLStephen.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist` worked for me.

Comment: On Mavericks, I found that it wasn't sufficient to comment out those lines in the `/System/Library/QuickLook/Web.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist`. The only way I could make it work with HTML files was to add those lines to the `QLColorCode.qlgenerator` file, while at the same time turning completely <b>off</b> the `Web.qlgenerator`

Comment: On Sierra I just had to add the 2 lines to: `~/Library/QuickLook/QLColorCode.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist`